# Too many folders, no organization

Tags: excel, windows, cmd

Working on archiving a boatload of project folders (wasn't getting done for a while before I stumbled in). Active and inactive projects are in the same directory, and it's way past time to put the inactive projects in a retirement ho-drive...archival drive.

```
robocopy \\vm\projects\##-#### \\vm\archive\##-#### /e /sec /xo /xa:hs /r:1 /w:1 /v /fp /tee /log+:dir\logDATE /blahblahblah
```

TL;AGR - How am I going to replace the ##-####'s with a list I've generated (without typing each of the 800-ish names out)?

This is what the previous admin left, and it's fine for a monthly project archive (finishing maybe 30 projects a month and manually entering their names). I'm now reporting 1100 projects in this directory, 800 of which don't appear on my active project list.

It's important to note that these projects are not named logically, there's no "active" tag (outside of our management software), and that their appearance in any sort is random.

I've exported an .xls and cleaned it up, leaving only a list of inactive projects. Now I'm stuck and I'd rather not waste too much time with manual entry, although I'm game if there isn't an easier solution...

Thanks!

-Ian

Comment: You could write a small Excel VBA routine to go through your list of filenames and move the files. This might help. It's not exactly what you want but might give you enough to work out the tweaks. You can store your files to move in an array. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4589-excel-move-files-from-one-folder-to-another.html

Comment: Where's your list? in excel? You can use excel formulas to generate the appropriate robocopy commmand line and paste it into a .cmd file.

Comment: or save your list as `csv` and parse it with batch (`for /f "delims=" %%a in (my_list.csv) do echo %%a`)

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out shortly after posting:
With the project numbers in a single column, I wrote a concatenate command around the project number, pulled the first two characters to name a folder in which each prefix got sorted, then ctrl+dragged the formula down the list. A simple copy/paste into a notepad document, save as batch, and run sorted the whole mess out. Thanks for the suggestions!

-Ian